# Laravel lighthouse JSON type

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

How can I add `JSON` type to lighthouse?

I've seen this package but I don't know how to use it and there's not any documentations available for it: https://github.com/mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars

Comment: just use search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you installed it, in your `schema.graphql` define every Scalar you want to use, like:

```
scalar JSON @scalar(class: "MLL\\GraphQLScalars\\JSON")

# Then just use it, like:
type User {
  id: ID!
  meta: JSON!
}
```